# ObjectMapper readValue always adds time zone at the end of XMLGregorianCalendar from a JSON date string

Tags: java, json, junit, xmlgregoriancalendar

I am writing a junit test case which I need to give the following data file (request):

```
  data_file:

  {
    "birthDate" : "2017-12-08"
   }
```

The junit test file uses:

```
     fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(data_file)
```

to read this request data file and convert the date into XMLGregorianCalendar.  However, the converted value has a "Z" at the end, I think that is the default time zone:

```
     2017-12-08T00:00:00.000Z
```

I can't change the java class that contains the code for reading the Json value because we don't own the code.  So what date string should I give in my test data file so that the "Z" won't appear at the end of converted XMLGregorianCalendar value?

```
     2017-12-08T00:00:00.000
```

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don’t know how your JSON mapper gets to the result it does. I tried:

```
    System.out.println(
            DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar("2017-12-08"));
```

This prints

```
2017-12-08
```

No offset from UTC and also no time of day, just the same string as I fed into the `XMLGregorianCalendar`.

However, once you have got an `XMLGregorianCalendar`, say, `xgc`, you can remove the offset by setting it to undefined:

```
    xgc.setTimezone(DatatypeConstants.FIELD_UNDEFINED);
```

Now the `toString` method will produce a string without the `Z` in the end.